# How to see deadlock details in Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-deadlocks, azure-sql-server

I have some problems with DB deadlocks in my Java Spring Boot Web application that use an Azure SQL Server DB.

Which query can I run in order to get an history of recent deadlocks happend?

Azure AppInsights tells me only some generic informations like:

> Transaction (Process ID 79) was deadlocked on lock resources with
> another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
> transaction

and the query affected.

But not the transactions details fighting each other.

This query (that I found online) doesn't produce any resultset

```
 WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML)  AS [target_data_XML]
FROM sys.fn_xe_telemetry_blob_target_read_file('dl', null, null, null)
)
SELECT target_data_XML.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'DateTime2') AS Timestamp,
target_data_XML.query('/event/data[@name=''xml_report'']/value/deadlock') AS deadlock_xml,
target_data_XML.query('/event/data[@name=''database_name'']/value').value('(/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS db_name
FROM CTE
```

and this other query (suggest from my DBA) seems returning only some information lock (non deadlock) about indexes of current transactions.

```
SELECT  L.request_session_id AS SPID,
    DB_NAME(L.resource_database_id) AS DatabaseName,
    O.Name AS LockedObjectName,
    P.object_id AS LockedObjectId,
    L.resource_type AS LockedResource,
    L.request_mode AS LockType,
    ST.text AS SqlStatementText,       
    ES.login_name AS LoginName,
    ES.host_name AS HostName,
    TST.is_user_transaction as IsUserTransaction,
    AT.name as TransactionName,
    CN.auth_scheme as AuthenticationMethod
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks L
    JOIN sys.partitions P ON P.hobt_id = L.resource_associated_entity_id
    JOIN sys.objects O ON O.object_id = P.object_id
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ES ON ES.session_id = L.request_session_id
    JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions TST ON ES.session_id = TST.session_id
    JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AT ON TST.transaction_id = AT.transaction_id
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections CN ON CN.session_id = ES.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CN.most_recent_sql_handle) AS ST
WHERE   resource_database_id = db_id()
ORDER BY L.request_session_id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database are you running the first query against? It needs to be run against `master`

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks you are right, I didn't execute it against the master DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database there are already running an Extended Event that captures the deadlocks without any additionally action for customer side.

1. As @MartinSmith suggested, your first query should run in master DB.

   You can analyze your deadlock graphs by copying the deadlock_xml result into an xdl file and opening it with SSMS. This query can run slowly if you have a large number of deadlocks, it also is hard to get an overall of what is going on if you have a large number of deadlocks.
2. The next query will help you analyze a large number of deadlocks by giving you a count of deadlocks by database, query, and the resource it is waiting on.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS [target_data_XML] FROM sys.fn_xe_telemetry_blob_target_read_file('dl', null, null, null)
)
SELECT [db_name], [query_text], [wait_resource], COUNT(*) as [number_of_deadlocks] FROM (
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Replace(Replace(c.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)'),CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(13),' '))) as query_text,
D.value('@waitresource', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [wait_resource],
target_data_XML.query('/event/data[@name=''database_name'']/value').value('(/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [db_name]
from CTE CROSS APPLY target_data_XML.nodes('(/event/data/value/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf)') AS T(C)
CROSS APPLY target_data_XML.nodes('(/event/data/value/deadlock/process-list/process)') AS Q(D)
) deadlock
GROUP BY [query_text], [wait_resource], [db_name]
ORDER BY [number_of_deadlocks] DESC
```

From above code you can get a trend of what specific queries and objects are causing deadlocking with in your databases.

3. Finally you can get the deadlock graphs for a specific object with this query. Replace `<YourDB>` with the database name and `<wait_resource>` with the wait resource identified from the query above.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS [target_data_XML] FROM sys.fn_xe_telemetry_blob_target_read_file('dl', null, null, null)
)
SELECT [db_name], [wait_resource], [deadlock_xml] FROM (
SELECT target_data_XML.query('/event/data[@name=''database_name'']/value').value('(/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [db_name],
waitresource_node.value('@waitresource', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [wait_resource],
deadlock_node.query('.') as [deadlock_xml]
FROM CTE CROSS APPLY target_data_XML.nodes('(/event/data/value/deadlock)') AS T(deadlock_node)
CROSS APPLY target_data_XML.nodes('(/event/data/value/deadlock/process-list/process)') AS U(waitresource_node)
) deadlock
WHERE [db_name] = '<YourDB>'
AND [wait_resource] = '<wait_resource>'
```

Source: [Deadlock analysis for SQL Azure Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/deadlock-analysis-for-sql-azure-database/ba-p/368883)