# Azure Data Factory "Stored Procedure Activity" causes SQL server deadlock error 1205

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, deadlock

In Azure Data Factory, I have a "Stored Procedure Activity" that executes a stored procedure which updates a single row in a single table in Azure SQL Server database instance (simple table update without joining to other tables).

I understand that SQL Server deadlock 1205 error occurs when two processes collide because each one is trying to reach a resource while locking another resource needed for the opposing process.

But in my case, my stored procedure is targeting one resource only (without locking another), so it should not collide with any other concurrently running processes and causes a deadlock because simply it could just wait.

PS: the error appears and goes away randomly (meaning: the pipeline could run for days normally, then the error shows up again)

I only made sure that no other pipelines are accessing the same stored procedure (or the related table) at the same time. but the deadlock error still show up sometimes.

Comment: Do you have access to extended events in your sql server environment? You can actually figure out what the deadlocking processes are and go from there

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444889/how-to-see-deadlock-details-in-azure-sql-server) for a T-SQL query that gets deadlock details from telemetry XE, which captures the processes involved. Make sure indexes exists on the table to ensure only the single row to be updated is touched. Touching more rows than needed (scans) often cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

As per My understanding even stored procedure is targeting one resource only,
There are chances still to get  a deadlock error

1> If there are other Activities or Pipelines accessing the same Table or even multiple transactions.

2> If other pipelines are accessing the same stored procedure or table at the same time.
For an example I have 2 tables I am using a Stored procedure updates a single row in a single table.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateUserName
    @UserId INT,
    @NewName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    -- Start a transaction 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    
    SELECT @NewName = UPPER(@NewName); -- Convert name to uppercase
    
    UPDATE Users WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) -- Use row-level locking to avoid deadlocks
    SET Name = @NewName
    WHERE UserId = @UserId;
    
    -- Commit the transaction
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

[image]
[image]
In this stored procedure I am  starting a transaction using the BEGIN TRANSACTION statement.
This helps the update operation.

Lock on the row to  update using the WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK)  in the UPDATE statement.

With this the SQL Server  uses row-level locking and update locking to avoid deadlocks.
Row-level locking ensures that only the specific row being updated is locked.
Rather than the entire table.

After updating the row, I am using commit the transaction using the COMMIT TRANSACTION statement.
I am using the same Stored Procedure in Pipeline.
[image]

Stored Procedure Parameters:
[image]

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

In this way the DEADLOCK ERROR while using Stored Procedures can be avioded and imporve the Performance.